# Why does not the bare interaction potential appear in the Bogoliubov theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, renormalization, superfluidity

They use some effective potential defined by the s-wave scattering length, but not the bare atom-atom interaction $V(r)$.

Why?

It is standard practice in second quantization to use the bare interaction and then transform to the momentum space.

Comment: What is the "bare" atom-atom interaction? Of course at large distances it will look like $V(r)\sim 1/r^6$ for neutral atoms. But what about when $r$ is comparable to the Bohr radius?

Comment: It should be a repulsive core.

Comment: Until the electron orbitals start to overlap, at which point the scattering problem is a many-electron problem and the concept of an atom-atom potential no longer makes sense. My point is that there does not exist any "bare" potential $V(r)$, there are only effective potentials valid beyond a certain radius. If you want to use the Lennard-Jones potential, you find that its Fourier transform is divergent as $k\to\infty$, due to the singularity as $r\to 0$. But if you don't care about physics at this scale, you replace it with a pseudo-potential whose Fourier transform is simple to work with.